# why use "have been married" in this sentence?

Tags: tense, usage

[image]

This is an example from Unit 11 of the book English Grammar in Use. I want to know why this example isn't using **"have been marrding"** or **"have married"**

> Thank you so much!

Comment: *Married* is an adjective, not a verb form.

Comment: If you mean **have been marrying**, it's because **to marry** is a verb meaning 'perform a marriage ceremony' or 'have a ceremony performed for you'.

Comment: Similarly "How long have they waited?" is fine but "How long have they married?" doesn't work because married as a verb refers to the ceremony not to the state of being husband and wife.

Comment: Posting photos of text is frowned upon here because it can't be searched or accessed by screen readers, so please type out the text. Also please edit the question to correct your typos, and say what exact sentences you would expect to see and why.

Comment: to be married, to be divorced=idioms Generally, marrying is not an ongoing activity: have been playing chess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Married" can mean both *the act of marrying* (ie the wedding) and *the state of being married*. When it is the latter, an auxiliary verb is required:

- They married on a beautiful summer's day (*refers to the wedding*)
- They *are* married.
- They *have been married* for 10 years.
- They *were* married for 7 years until they divorced.

Auxiliary verbs help the main verb to express tense or voice - in this case, to indicate that it is a period of time.

Comment: Or even: *They were married seven years ago today by Pastor Williams out back under the gazebo.*

Comment: @tchrist indeed but that auxiliary verb is required for a different reason, the fact that you are referring to a third party performing the marriage.